# Sentiment Analysis in C# using Rank Selection method of Genetic Algorithm

Tags: genetic-algorithm, sentiment-analysis

- I am developing an application for analyizing the sentiment of the movie reviews (good/bad/neutral). The frontend will be C# dot net and backend will be MySQL.
- The algorithm I am using is Genetic Algorithm and I am only directed by my guide that I need to use Rank Selection method.

I'm looking at how to approach this and if there are any existing source codes which I can refer.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use external API for sentiment analysis for example [text2data.org](http://text2data.org/)

There is also free option 
[nltk.org](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html)